# RACObserve not working

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to observe a property in my ViewModel, and then update a label with it's value using ReactiveCocoa, but it's not updating.

Here's what I got:

ViewModel

```
var amount: NSDecimalNumber
```

ViewController

```
RAC(self.amountLabel, "text") <~ RACObserve(self.viewModel, "amount").map({
            (value) -> AnyObject! in
                let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                numberFormatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

                return numberFormatter.stringFromNumber(value as NSDecimalNumber)
        })
```

I checked and the ViewModel is updating the 'amount' property correctly. Is there anything I'm missing here?

I also tried this for testing:

```
RACObserve(self.viewModel, "amount").subscribeNext { 
    (value) -> Void in
        println(value)
}
```

Doesn't work either.

I'm using ReactiveCocoa 2.4.7 because my app is supporting iOS 7. Are there any incompatibilities between the macro replacements in Swift [1,2] and this version?

[1] - https://github.com/ashfurrow/Swift-RAC-Macros

[2] - http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/07/24/mvvm-reactivecocoa-swift.html

Comment: By the way, read Ivan's comment in [the second reference](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/07/24/mvvm-reactivecocoa-swift.html). The RACObserve in Swift is different from RACObserve macro in Objective-C, and it can be a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mark the property as `dynamic`, and make sure the view model inherits NSObject.

```
class MyViewModel: NSObject {
    dynamic var amount: NSDecimalNumber
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mark the property as 'dynamic'. Thanks!